# Browser loading fonts when I load home page

Tags: css, angular, font-face, roboto

I am using angular 4 and roboto-fontface. When I load my page downloading fonts in browser. How can I stop downloading the fonts ? Below is my css.

```
main.css

@import '../node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css';

  body {
  font-family: Roboto,Arial, sans-serif;
  }
```

In browser fonts are loading from below url

```
    http://localhost:4300/app/Roboto-Medium.2741a14e49524efa6059.woff2
```

Please help me

Comment: What's the problem? Do you want to load Arial or load Roboto? Why do you want to stop the font loading? Right now you are importing Roboto as a local resource what's the problem?

Comment: Explain the problem, stop downloading the fonts? You can just download them and add them locally, under a path in your project

Comment: If you see it's "downloading" them from `http://localhost:4300` it just means it's taking them from the local files. Otherwise it would start a fetch request to some google servers!

Comment: Thanks for responding, My browser is loading the fonts, I don't want to load in browser. Its taking 50kb size when I check in my browser network.

Comment: why won't you just remove them from the body CSS?